# Chance of getting k out of n Answers right in a multiple choice "pairing" test

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose I have a set of n questions and n answers and the task is to assign the correct answer to each question. There is only one correct answer for each question.

The chance of getting all n pairs right should be $\frac{1}{n!}$ because there are $n!$ posibilities for pairing questions and answers and only one of them is fully correct.

What is the chance of getting k out of n pairs right?

If I have two pairs right, then this could be question 1+2, 1+3..2+3 ..  i.e. there are $n\choose 2$ ways. But this number is too low, because there are sill many possibilities to get the remaining  $n-2$ pairs all wrong. So if I knew the possibilities to get $n-2$ pairs completely wrong I would be done.

But I don't know how to do this. And maybe there is a completely different approach.

Comment: I think this sounds as a formulation of the matching problem. (http://www.randomservices.org/random/urn/Matching.html)

Comment: Read about derangements, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A derangement is an arrangement where no object is in its proper place,
$D_n$ denoting a derangement of $n$ objects, and can be computed as $\lfloor{{\frac{n!}{e}}+0.5\rfloor}$

We can take the questions to be in serial order, and a matching answer to be in its proper place, and  solve the problem using *partial derangements*

If k answers are correct, this could be in $\binom{n}{k}$ ways, but we have also to get the remaining $(n-k)$ answers, wrong,

thus Pr = $\dfrac{\binom{n}{k}\cdot D_{(n-k)}}{n!}$